# Python: pip install won't work on any packages

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm currently using MacOS (10.13.4) and Python 2.7.14.

I can't get pip to install any packages at all. All I get is the following error

```
    Collecting scrapy
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scrapy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scrapy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scrapy
```

Just for reference here is another packages error message:

```
Collecting dateutil
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/dateutil/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dateutil
```

Not sure if this is relevant but heres this as well:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

And from Python:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Any help at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try using `--trusted-host` for `pypi.python.org`

Comment: I did. It is still returning the same error message.